# How to make latexmk show warnings even when compilation is up to date

Tags: warnings, latexmk

`latexmk` is a great tool for many reasons, but one in particular is that it prints out many of the important the latex warnings (such as missing references, duplicate labels, etc.) at the end, so one doesn't have to scroll through pages and pages of latex output to find them.  Unfortunately, it only does this when it actually runs latex.  That is, if I run `latexmk` when the compilation is already up to date, there is no printout of warnings.  To see them, I have to make a trivial change to the latex file and then run `latexmk` again.  Is there a flag I can pass to `latexmk` to get it to print out the warnings even when the target is already up to date? (they're in the log file, so this would be trivial to implement).

Comment: You can probably submit it as a feature request. John Collins (the maintainer) is on the site, so he'll probably see your question at some point

Comment: Look at the log file.

Comment: From the man page, it seems that one wants `-logfilewarnings` (option) or `$silence_logfile_warnings = 0;` (RC file), but this doesn't work.

Comment: I take that back... seems to be working, though my IDE plugin is not.